# Minimums for using iMessage

Tags: iphone, ios

Upfront:  100% not an Apple/iPhone guy. But that is about to be 99%  ;-)

I have a group of friends at the gym. They are great folk, but have some weird thing about using iMessage for communicating together.  I'm a complete Android/Pixel guy, and so I can't participate.

They have successfully shamed me into joining them. I'm not going to switch over completely, but I am willing to get a second-hand, used phone/iPod to join them in the dreaded iMessage world.

I assume I don't need a cell plan and can use Wi-fi for iMessage. (Though I realize this assumption could be wrong.

What are the minimum requirements needed?  What version of iOS do I need?

Comment: To avoid getting your question flagged, you should remove the hardware sourcing question from the OP. Not only would it generate opinionated answers, as we don't know where you are or what supplier options you have, multiple questions per post are discouraged. As to the main body, see my answer.

Comment: @AndyGriffiths  Done -- thanks.

Comment: Why do you think you need to get an Apple device? Messages on iOS can send to SMS. I have a number of group chats that contain a mix of iOS and Android users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iMessages can be sent to an email identifier as well as a phone number. So when you setup your device (presumably without a SIM if you get an iPhone), you will also setup an Apple ID. This can be an existing email address from your existing usage. You can then set this as your iMessage 'address' and pass onto your contacts. `Settings | Messages | Send & Receive`

As to minimum iOS version, whatever comes on the device, upgraded to the current the device supports, should suffice. You'll not want a device (nor likely to find one 2nd hand) that only supports up to iOS 6, the minimum for iMessage. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204230 for the minimum system requirements for all the iCloud features.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know -- thanks.

Comment: @Thinkr, try reading the Apple document as the canon, rather than the inaccurate Wiki, which only states it was intro'ed in 5. The doc I link to clearly states iOS6. While Apple introduced it in iOS5, the minimum requirements are now a version higher, probably for security etc. You obviously skimmed my answer...

Comment: Regarding “This can be an existing email address from your existing usage”. IME that’s not correct any more. I have an Apple ID with a non-Apple address, but when it came time to set my kids up, I had to create new @icloud.com addresses for them.

Comment: @Darren as completely separate Apple accounts, or as part of Family sharing? Even as part of a Family, non-iCloud addresses are supported. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201084 so I don't know why your case went wrong. Either way, irrelevant to OP, as even for a first account you are given the choice, would be bad for interoperability / convenience if not. See also https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204316

Comment: @AndyGriffiths it was to add them to family sharing. I assumed it was some new policy of Apples. It would t be the craziest policy enforced by a tech company (cf. MS enforcing Edge as a default browser as often as it can).